# QGIS GDALtools plugin problem

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I am trying to use the GDAL merge tool and receive the following error message:

> The process failed to start. Either the invoked program is missing, or
>   you may have insufficient permissions to invoke the program.

On install I checked the "Path to the GDAL Executables" and it already had the /usr/bin added to the install. Here is what I have in this field:

> /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.9/Programs/usr/bin

Thanks in advance for any help with this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the path you have shown, I'm going to assume you are using a Mac. Also assuming you have used the standard [KyngChaos.com installer for GDAL](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks).

Try this path instead:

```
/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.9/Programs
```

The `'Versions/1.9/Programs/usr/bin'` subdirectory doesn't exist, but the `Versions/1.9/unix/bin` does and should only contain the `gdal-config` tool (not used by GDALTools plugin). The binaries used by the GDALTools plugin should all be located in the Programs directory listed above.

Test by running the Raster->Miscellaneous->Information tool on a raster layer.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I receive tis strange error when running the info tool. Not sure if this is an error on my end. I am using a raster dataset I am unfamiliar with. "ERROR 4: `/Users/jdlancaster/Desktop/canyon_city-w' does not exist in the file system,
and is not recognised as a supported dataset name.

gdalinfo failed - unable to open '/Users/jdlancaster/Desktop/canyon_city-w'.

Comment: Nevermind last post. I placed the raster files under a new directory and forgot to change this in the GIS. It seems to work now, thanks for your help.